# How to convert an existing PHP library file so it can be used in a CakePHP framework?

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, datasource, cakephp-1.3

I have this library in PHP non-Cake format, the usual PHP scripting which currently works like a charm. I need to use this in a Cake framework. The library file is as follow: (example extracted)

```
<?php

// REST API functions

function sendAction($itemurl, $itemimageurl, $sessionid, $userid, $rating=""){
    
    global $someapiwebsiteURL, $apiKey, $tenantId;
    $somewebsiteAPI = $someapiwebsiteURL.$action."?apikey=".$apiKey.
                                                                 .....
                ................
    }
    

    //Codes extract


?>
```

I've come across a few ways of doing it. Currently confused, how am I going to place this library file into my Cake framework?

1. App::import()
2. Datasource

The functions in the library file above (I supposed it'd be used in one of my Controllers to render the data outputting through the view).

Currently working in a non-Cake framework structure, the view page is such as: (example extracted)

```
<?php
// my view page
 
$viewResponse = sendAction($itemdescription ,$itemurl , $itemimageurl,$sessionid,$userid);

//sample code only
?>
```

Both the files are working fine. The logic of putting it in a CakePHP framework is the problem here. Anyone may suggest "the" way of doing this without over-strenuously working on a data source? If we have to use a data source in App/models/datasources/, how exactly is the structure of it? Like, e.g., in datasource file, do we include the library functions? or is it some generic ReST datasource file which can be found here: [CakePHP ReST datasource](https://github.com/neilcrookes/CakePHP-ReST-DataSource-Plugin) . I've gone through the cookbook chapter on datasource and understand we have to define the datasource in our database.php, but if someone is certain about their way of accomplishing it either using datasource or app::import() method, please share with more details?

**UPDATE:**

Hi Lionel!, thanks for filling up. Well, actually users will click on view action: function view (){} in my foods_controller. I'm appending some scripts here to include my view function in my foods_controller so maybe it may help you to help out easier. Thanks..

```
function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid food', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->set('food', $this->Food->read(null, $id));       
    }
```

- The view action triggers the send_action function, (each time a user clicks on view page on foods controller). So each time, a user clicks on view action, his (dynamic variables): userid, sessionid, that page's itemid, url, itemdescription; (timerange value is a static string value "ALL"), and if any (etc.), so far only these values are available: Will be used as the "parameters" in the Send Action function. What you wrote is close to what the codes can do. You're right. Except we should include the Send Action function inside the view() in foods controller?
- If we look at dynamically filling in the variables mentioned in the point above, could you modify your second code (the code from your product_controller, e.g.) so it also works to receive the variables dynamically? (as you asked in the last update: how to get the parameters..)
- Just to make it clear.

  1. A user views the page. The send action collects data and send to the API. (as we've already done by calling the function in the library the (ACME.php). *just waiting for your update if possible, thanks.
  2. In the function view() of the foods controller: there's also an additional calling. The (2)second calling which is this:

`$recommendResponse = getRecommendations("otherusersviewed", $itemId, $userId);`

The second calling calls the ACME.php library file in which there consists the (2)second function that retrieves data, here it is: (it's in working order, but just needs to be changed into a public static function like you did for the (1)first function. Could you help to modify this code too, please?:

```
function getRecommendations($recommendationType, $itemId, $userId){
    
    // sample code similar to the first one.
}
```

That's all to it. It seems quite simple in the normal PHP format, and it works easily, but getting  it on an MVC framweork is a bit challenging for some, a lot for me. Thanks for helping out, Lionel. :-)

P.S. Hi Lionel, I notice something missing in the library after changes? Look originally we have this:

`$somewebsiteAPI = $someapiwebsiteURL.$action."?apikey=".$apiKey.`

Look, the variables for `$SomeWebsiteAPI` and `$SomeApiWebsiteURL` are different. Did I miss out something? or you have modified so it is more efficient ? I see that the variable named `$SomeWebsiteAPI` is modified to become variable called `$link` ? and variable `$SomeApiWebsiteURL` is changed to the named variable, `$url`, am I right ? .. thanks.

> Thanks, best regards. John Maxim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, if I have this piece of code, I would first wrap it into a static (or normal) class, and named it ACME, then I will move the acme.php into `/apps/libs/acme.php`. Then in the controller, I will use `App::import('Lib', 'acme')`. This action do nothing but just requiring the file, so you can just use it instantly by calling `ACME::sendAction(...)`.

And regarding the `global` thing, you might just need to declare a static (or normal) class, then define the shared variables as part of the class properties, so you can share them among all the functions in the class.

For example, this is the `/app/libs/acme.php`

```
class ACME {

    private static $someapiwebsiteURL = "http://thewebsite/api/1.0/"; 
    private static $apiKey = "0010KIUMLA0PLQA665JJ";   
    private static $tenantId = "THE_TENANT_NAME";

    /**
     * Simple builder to build links from array of $params
     *
     * @param string $url The api url
     * @param array $params The given parameters
     * @return string built url
     */
    private static function BuildLink($url="", $params=array()) {

        $link = $url;
        foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
            $link .= "&$k=$v";
        }

        //Replace the first & to ?
        $link = preg_replace("/&/", "?", $link, 1);

        //Not sure if we need URL encode here, please uncomment this
        //if the API could not work.
        //$link = urlencode($link);

        return $link;
    }

    public static function SendAction($action, $itemId, $itemdescription, $itemurl, $itemimageurl, $sessionid, $userid, $rating="") {

        $somewebsiteAPI = self::BuildLink(self::$someapiwebsiteURL.$action, array(
            "apikey"=>self::$apiKey,
            "sessionid"=>$sessionid,
            "userid"=>$userid,
            "tenantid"=>self::$tenantId,
            "itemid"=>$itemId,
            "itemdescription"=>$itemdescription,
            "itemurl"=>$itemurl,
            "itemimageurl"=>$itemimageurl,

            /**
             * Assuming your API smart enough to only use this value when
             * the action is "rate"
             */
            "ratingvalue"=>$rating 
        ));

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($somewebsiteAPI);
        return $xml;
    }

    public static function GetRecommendations($recommendationType, $itemId, $userId) {
        $somewebsiteAPI = self::BuildLink(self::$someapiwebsiteURL.$recommendationType, array(
            'apikey'=>self::$apiKey,
            'tenantid'=>self::$tenantId,
            'itemid'=>$itemId,
            'userid'=>$userId
        ));

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($somewebsiteAPI);
        return $xml;
    }
}
```

And in your controller

```
App::import('Lib', 'acme');

class FoodController extends AppController {

    //Food is plural already I assume? You can just use
    //food, should be ok I think, else it will be weird
    //to use /foods/view/?
    var $name = "Food";
    var $uses = array("Item", "Food");

    function view($id="") {
        //We accepts only valid $id and $id > 0.
        //Take notes that this $id will be a string, not int.
        if (ctype_digit($id) && $id > 0) {


            //I don't know how you would gather the information, but I assume you
            //have a database with the information ready.

            //I assumed you have an `items` table
            $item = $this->Item->findById($id);

            $sessionid = "00988PPLO899223NHQQFA069F5434DB7EC2E34"; //$this->Session->...?
            $timeRange = "ALL";
            $userid = "24EH1725550099LLAOP3"; //$this->Auth->user('id')?

            if (!empty($item)) {
                $desc = $item['Item']['description'];
                $url = "/foods/view/".$id;
                $img = $item['Item']['img'];

                $viewResponse = ACME::SendAction("view", $id, $desc ,$url, $img, $sessionid, $userid);
                $this->set('food', $this->Food->read(null, $id));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid food', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }    
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid food', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));    
        }

    }

}
```

**Edit**

The code has been filled up, and of course, without any warranty :). I personally don't really like to have long arguments in a function (like `SendAction`, error prune), rather use shorter one like the `$params` in `ACME::BuildLink`. But just to respect your code, I didn't modify much on the `SendAction` method.

Then I'm not too sure how you would make use of this code, so I assumed you have a `ProductsController`, and somehow the user trigger url like `/products/send_action/`. If you can provide more information, then we would be able to help out.

**Edit Again**

I have modified the ACME class, as well as the controller. Yea I do miss out some variables, but I had added them back to the updated code.

Not too sure if it would work (perhaps typo), you can just modify the code if it doesn't work for you.

And for personal conventions, I usually capitalize methods which are static, like `ACME:GetRecommendations` or `ACME::SendAction`.

Oh yea, I better stick back to the variables you used. Sorry for modifying them, just I don't like long names :)

And btw, the RoadRunner's *ACME Corporation*? Lol!

Cheers
Lionel

Comment: Hi Lionel, can you help to write the SendAction function in my acme.php: as written by you, what should be the parameters and the body of the public static function SendAction (..) ?. And my controller code: you've written as function the_action().. what should be the name of the_action? can you also lengthen what is inside the function the_action() body {} ?. Thanks this is certainly helpful.

Comment: Hi @John, I posted the code as an edit to my answer. Feel free to change the code if it does not meet your needs.

Comment: Hi Lionel, I have copied your codes, thanks for that. I've updated how basically I'm going to use the codes in my original post. But it's still far from complete I guess. At least, it's over 50% MVC compatible now. Could you look at the update and amend any changes if required? Thanks...

Comment: Yep updated the code accordingly. Have a look and see if that meets your requirement :)

Comment: Thanks reading now, will update when I have questions. Doing the documentation. Well, ACME? haha... no not the cartoon. Just an example company.  :-)  cheers.

Comment: Sure, and hope the modification helps :)

Comment: Lionel, I just scanned through your comments and here's my explanation: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_plural_form_of_food :-) It's common to think food as plural too, but as this is a final thesis, I got to read a lot about foods! and later found out that foods may be more appropriate in my write-up documentation, depending as explained in the link.

Comment: * Shock *. No one explained it to me! My mother tongue is not English, so please forgive me :)

Comment: Hi Lionel, I just updated my comment above... well my mother tongue isn't English too. But I speak English better than my native language, or than the language my home speaks. I stay out often I guess that's why.

Comment: No problem man :) Happy coding! Cake is really fun, hope you would like it and make use of it in future projects!

Comment: Hi Lionel, could you confirm with the buildlink() function? the variables $url and $link, aren't they supposed to be $somewebsiteAPI and $someapiwebsiteURL ? I'm getting error as I import it into my controller (Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_FUNCTION' in *..\app\controllers\foods_controller.php on line 8); I haven't put in the function that calls the library yet. If I only import the library and do nothing in the controller, it shouldn't be giving me error right?

Comment: Hi John, sorry for late reply. The whole ACME class is correct and I tested locally. According to your error something is wrong in foods_controller, not acme.php, so it must have something wrong with the foods_controller, mainly syntax error. And btw, the `BuildLink` is correct, it is just a "helper" on helping you concatenating the parameters into a long url. No relation to your API :)

Comment: Hi Lionel, I loaded the library alright with no error. Now I'm trying to output some data. For testing, I changed all the variables into static, and output data through the view page. It's done this way: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/44138268 But I get 3 errors as stated in the link, you may read the errors. It is working if it's in non-Cake structure (even after changing my library into a class), I just don't understand how to place the codes so it works in Cake. (MVC). Could pls you modify the codes from the link so it suits Cake structure?

Comment: Hi John, the controller above has already imported the file with `App::import("Lib", "acme");`. You can place this line anywhere in the controller file, or in the beginning, as recommended. Then, for the error you seen, it's because you are trying to use `$rankingResponse` in the view without `$this->set(..)` in the controller. All the 3 errors refer to the same problem.

Comment: If you don't mind you can zip & send over your code snippets/folder to my gmail if you want. Include sample sql perhaps.

Comment: Hi Lionel, what's your gmail ?? Sure I would send over. So sorry I went out for a social meeting. And just got home. Thanks..thanks..

Comment: I've actually set the `$rankingResponse` in my controller: I used this: `$this->set('Rank', $rankingResponse);` in my view I've also modified it as: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/44138268 before I posted here, just so don't want to confuse you, that's why I send the plain one. I still get undefined variable for $rankingResponse from controller if I defined as shown in the link.

Comment: The exact error I'm getting after defining rankingResponse variable is this: `Notice (8): Undefined variable: Rank [APP\controllers\foods_controller.php, line 45]` where line 45 is `$this->set('Rank', $rankingResponse);` to be exact how I place the code it's here: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/44138268

Comment: Yea just send the whole package as well as the sql dump. So I would be able to test it out locally. My gmail/talk is chaoszcat[at]gmail, cheers :)

Comment: The reason why your "Rank" is undefined because of your `if (!id)` is wrong. Let's say id is `3`, `if (!3) = if (!true) = if (false)`, your code only executed if `$id` is `null` or `0`. You can use `ctype_digit` like the one I used in the code